# Handle two different queries with one ref cursor

Tags: plsql, dynamic-sql, ref-cursor

I have two select queries and i wanted to 
open cursor for both of them ?

```
v_str1:='SELECT ROWID FROM ' || p_tblname|| 'WHERE '|| p_cname||'='''||
       p_cvalue || '''';
```

v_str2:='SELECT   COUNT ( * )
     INTO   v_cnt
     FROM  '                                                                                                            ||
      p_tblname||
    'WHERE  '|| p_cname||' = '''||p_cvalue||'''';

.....

OPEN ref_cur_name FOR v_str1 
   LOOP

```
  IF v_cnt = 1
  THEN
     EXIT;
  ELSE

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM '||  p_tblname||
           'WHERE   ROWID = REC.ROWID';
  END IF;

  v_cnt := v_cnt - 1;
```

END LOOP;

First query is a select statement and other just puts the count into `v_cnt`  . Now i need to execute both of these queries . now is there a way to  use both these queries ?

Also there is a syntax error after `OPEN` statement i.e . at LOOP.

Comment: please share error message  ?

Comment: ` Found 'LOOP', Expecting: ;  USING   -or-   ||   -or-   /   -or-   **   -or-   (+)   -or-   %  .  [   -or-   :  @  CASE  CONNECT_BY_ROOT  decimal number  EXISTS  FALSE  float  integer  NEW  PRIOR  SQL  TRUE   -or-   (  *  +  -  AT  CONTINUE  CURSOR  DAY  identifier  MOD  MODEL  MULTISET  NOT  NULL  REM  string  THE  WHEN  YEAR`

Comment: I was missing semicolon after open .

Comment: I got the solution.Th eproblem was a semicolon;

Answer (score 0):

Use Execute immediate

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT   COUNT ( * )
 INTO   v_cnt
 FROM  '                                                                                                            ||
  p_tblname||
'WHERE  '|| p_cname||' = '''||p_cvalue||'''';
```